# Fantasy novel featuring armies of demons and a rift

Tags: story-identification, novel

I recall in high school reading a fantasy novel published in the late '70s/early '80s.

It featured a kingdom or citadel on one side of a rift, and on the other side burial sites haunted by demons that sometimes formed armies to attack the humans, especially if the humans ventured across the rift.